# jquery-ias is not working on mobile platforms

Tags: jquery-ias

As per infinitescroll.com documentation, I have added the following piece of code which works fine on desktop browser BUT on mobile browser it doesn't load the content as I scroll down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ias({
        container:  '#mobileVideos',
        item:       '.mobileVideoDiv',
        pagination: '#mobilePagination',
        /*delay: '1500',*/
        next:       '.mobileNext'
    });
});
```

Just in case if it helps I was doing some trial and error with my code and figured out that removing the line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">` from the HTML header fixes the problem but it is messing up my website's view so that's clearly not a solution. Does anyone have any clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out a solution. I replaced the above piece of code with the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ias = $('.mobileContent').ias({
          container:  '#mobileVideos',
          item:       '.mobileVideoDiv',
          pagination: '#mobilePagination',
          delay:      '1250',
          next:       '.mobileNext'
      });
});
```

so in short what I am doing here is instead of relying up on the browser scrollbar I am telling jquery-ias to add a scrollbar on a particular "div" element.